# Flutter web: tried to call a non-function, such as null: 'dart.global.firebase.storage

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage, flutter-web

Im using Firebase plugin for web and managed to work with firestore and authentication. Now, Im trying to enable firebase storage but when i instanciate Storage gives me this error

```
tried to call a non-function, such as null: 'dart.global.firebase.storage
```

for firestore and authentication I use :

```
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' as fb;
import 'package:firebase/firestore.dart';

 fb.Auth _firebaseAuth = fb.auth();
  Firestore _firestore =fb.firestore();
```

for Storage :

```
fb.Storage storage = fb.storage();
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Solved!**

In **index.html** add the latest version of firebase storage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    <script defer src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

In **yourClass.dart** :

```
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' as fb;

  fb.StorageReference _ref = fb.storage().ref('images');
```

Comment: Please answer my question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60832658/flutter-web-tried-to-call-a-non-function-such-as-null-dart-global-myfunction

Comment: Make sure you have same version of all the scripts.