# Flutter web: tried to call a non-function, such as null: 'dart.global.myFunction'

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have seen and tried the answers given in the following SO questions :

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57242045/flutter-web-tried-to-call-a-non-function-such-as-null-dart-global-firebase-s/57244054#57244054)

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845528/calling-javascript-from-dart/13845699#13845699)

Here's what I am doing :

This is my dart code :

```
@JS()
library t;

import "package:js/js.dart";

@JS("getHomeName")
external String getHostName();
```

I added this script before the main.dart.js script in the index.html :

```
  <script>
    function getHostName(){
      return "HOST NAME from javascript" ;
    }
  </script>
```

And i access this getHostName function from some other dart file like so :

```
import 'my_js_interface_thing' ; 
print("Got hostname : ${getHostName()}") ;
```

But I get the following error :

`Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: tried to call a non-function, such as null: 'dart.global.getHomeName'`

I presume this has something to do with how I am accessing the `getHostName` function from dart ? 
Unfortunately the `package:js` docs doesn't specify or give any code example regarding using the interface methods from within dart.

Comment: Looks like you have used a different name for the interop definition. `@JS("getHomeName")` instead of `@JS("getHostName")`.

Comment: Ohh god i'm such an idiot . Thanks you got it right ...

Comment: should i delete this question ?